# Waiting For Console Output From An Agent Issue

Tags: kubernetes

I get waiting for console output from an agent issue during the deployment to kubernetes. The message gets stuck for 1 day and after that it fails.

It fails at "kubectl rollout" job. I increased maximum and minimum number of scales and the result still seems same. I followed lots of forums and questions related to this topic but noone reported any solution about it.

Could you please help me to fix that issue ?

Thank you for your kind helps.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to roll out/scale? Can you use a different terminal while this is happening and investigate what the cluster is doing? Try running `kubectl get events` a few times while this is going on.

Comment: Where do you run your K8s cluster? on premise or any cloud provider?

Comment: İt is at cloud provider

Comment: @Tonyukuk which one? Have you seen that issue for Asure? - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/326645/waiting-for-console-output-from-an-agent-on-releas.html

Comment: İt is azure cloud provider

Comment: Do you have any A_Suh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer of the [Microsoft support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2018/09/27/liveness-in-release-management-ui/):

> Try the following URL to access your account:
>
> ```
> https://dev.azure.com/{your organization}/{your project}.
> ```
>
> If you use this URL to access your releases, then the live updates
>   will always work well for you.